# how to sort column(contains number and letter) by date, python

Tags: python, sorting

[my column that needs to be sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovOVv.png)

```
code:
allData["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(allData["Date"])
allData= allData.sort_values(by="Date")
print(allData)
```

> the error that i get:
> raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
> dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: 140820 new
>
> the result that i want is:

```
0    140820 new
1    150820 new
2    150820
3    101020
```

Comment: your date column is invalid? how do you think pandas will convert this `140820 new`?

Answer (score 0):

First your Date column is invalid.An it cant be sorted for first 2 rows in ascending order and remaining in descending order.
However, below is code is error free.
path = where your data is. [ assuming to be csv/txt file]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path,engine='python')
df['Date']=df["Date"].replace({'\t':' '}, regex=True)
print(df)
```